# `View` inside `View` leaving slight margin 

Tags: react-native

`View` inside `View` leaving slight margin. See red. Code is minimal, I will post if there isn’t a quick gotcha that someone knows about. In CSS, this is often a `line-height` culprit, not the case here as react native doesn’t have that property in `View`.

[image]

Comment: Whats the question? Do you need margin or remove it? You could achieve the same using css, (padding, margin). If you do not need space, thats the default behavior for views to cover 100%.

Comment: Yah need to remove the margin

Comment: The point is that the default behavior isn't working as expected

Comment: React native dont add margin/padding by default. It must have been casued by your css in parent component. You can inspect in simulator where this is been caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native do not add margin or padding by default. You might have added padding in your parent `View` or margin in your child.

You can use `Show Inspector` in your device where this is been caused.